# Soluble subgroups of 8-dimensional orthogonal groups over GF(4) transitive on nondegenerate 1-subspaces

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $V$ be an $8$-dimensional vector space over $GF(4)$ equipped with a nondegenerate plus type quadratic form, $G$ be an almost simple group with socle $L=\Omega^+(V)$, and $H$ be a soluble subgroup of $G$. If $H$ is transitive on nondegenerate 1-subspaces of $V$, then does there always exist a maximal parabolic of $G$ containing $H$?

Comment: I did some computer calculations in Magma, and I found that the only soluble subgroups of $\Gamma O^+_8(4)$ that were transitive on the 16320 nondegenerate 1-subspaces had nontrivial normal 2-subgroups, so the answer would appear to be yes.

Comment: @DerekHolt:By THEOREM A of Liebeck, Praeger and Saxl, The maximal factorizatins of the finite simple groups and their automorphism groups, I would be able to show that if $H$ is not contained in any maximal parabolic subgroup then $H\cap L$ is contained in $(L_2(16)\times L_2(16)).2^2$ (as $C_2$ or $C_3$ subgroup of $L$). Does this help?

Comment: @DerekHolt: What if $G$ contains a graph automorphism?

Comment: @DerekHolt:$N_G((PSL_2(16)\times PSL_2(16)).2^2)$ is maximal in $G$ if and only if $G=L$ or $L.2$, so by your computation for $\Gamma O_8^+(4)$, my statement holds. Thank you so much!